# Error when redirection to stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, next.js, vercel

I am building out an e-commerce site, with next.js and stripe checkout. I keep running into this error when I am going to checkout. I am using the `use-shopping-cart` package as well, and I'm starting to think it maybe causing the below response error from `stripe-checkout`

```
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid API Key provided: undefined",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

What is super confusing is that the checkout session in created, along with the cart and payment intent (I know this to be true because I can verify this information thru the stripe dashboard). Currently the stripe dashboard does not indicate there is an error either.

Has anyone experienced this, and does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the error says, you are not providing any api key for the request you are making to stripe. Can't know where your problem stands without knowing how you make that call

Comment: oh yeah of course. So I did some digging and was thinking that the error was coming from the secret key, turns out its the public key causing the issue. I have this getStripe util function:
`
import { Stripe, loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'

let stripePromise: Promise<Stripe | null>
const getStripe = () => {
  if (!stripePromise) {
    stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY!}` as string)
  }
  return stripePromise
}

export default getStripe
`
the public key variable is undefined, so when this is passed to my cart provider, I get the error.

Comment: dang sorry for that crappy formatting. The strange part is when I console log the public key, it logs in my terminal, but comes undefined in my console on the client. I'm using Next.js and a .env.local file at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

the solution is ridiculously easy. I just needed to prefix my env variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Comment: Correct, this exposes the environment variable on the client side! Glad it's working for you.